# How do I add Beufy on my Vue CLI project?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

So, I was looking for a css framework to use on my little project but I have issues adding it.

I use the latest Vue CLI, and tried to add it with `vue add buefy` and had no errors there.

*This is the main.js file*

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'


createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(Buefy).mount('#app')
```

And this is the error I get in the browser's console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Vue 3+? The `vue add buefy` is a plugin meant for Vue v3+. If you're using Vue 2 rather use `npm install buefy`. Then `import` it.